# interpreting MAT results for android memory leak

Tags: android, google-maps, memory-leaks

I have my app working now, except it has some serious memory leaks. I've watched the google I/O video and read the docs, but I'm still struggling to interpret the MAT results. One of the worst leaks comes from the map page, which uses this library to extend the map:

https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

I add the map like this:

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
SupportMapFragment f = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = f.getExtendedMap();
}
```

and here are the caps for the MAT shortest path to GC:
[image: leak 1]

[image: leak 2]

[image: leak3]

can anybody help me decipher them, or maybe suggest a way to plug the leaks? I would post the full code, but it's very long - let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Doesn't maps v2 have some inherent leaks in it that cannot be fixed?

Comment: Why do you only acquire GoogleMap object on first instance creation? @Rarw not so many anymore. Normal usage shouldn't be affected.

Comment: that was from something else - that apparently the fragmentmanager holds on to fragments. But you're right - it doesn't make any difference one way or the other. Nice library by the way - extremely useful!

Comment: I'm glad you like it. It is fun to write. I can't see memory leaks in these images. How do you there is a memory leak? Do you see multiple instances of fragments or activities of the same class in MAT?

Comment: It's a total lifesaver - I don't use the whole thing, but the bits I do use (clustering and marker get/set data) were complete headaches before I started using it (particularly coming from the js API where you take those things for granted). If you're accepting feature requests, it would be really nice to have a MIN_CLUSTER_SIZE parameter - clusters of two are kind of annoying.

Comment: (continued because I ran out of space): I think I'm on completely the wrong track here - I noticed the heap growing because I have an options menu that moves between activities. I think you might be right - it seems I need to add a flag to the intent to prevent multiple activities.

Comment: Clustering and setData is all there is. Sure I accept requests. Can you put it on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/issues/list)? I didn't say you need a flag. There might be a leak there. Just no proof in your code or these images. Using class fields (with `static`) is most common reason for a memory leak, but there are many other. Do you see OutOfMemoryErrors?

Comment: no out of memory errors, there was just a gradual creep in heap size as I moved around activities, but it seems to be under control now that there's (mostly) only one instance per activity. I don't know how else to prevent multiple instances of activities piling up except by putting launchMode="singleTop" in the manifest and flagging intents with FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP - is there a better way?